# Why does Eclipse JFace's Window class create a resize listener only to then immediately remove it?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jface

`org.eclipse.jface.window.Window`'s `create` method calls `createShell` which during it's run creates a `resizeListener`, which sets a `protected` flag for any resize that may have occurred, which can then be used by subclasses to handle appropriately upon closure and such. However, then it calls `initalizeBounds`, which *removes* this very same listener.

I'm a bit confused as to why. I tried googling this, but I couldn't find anything even acknowledging this. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this flag is just intended for the `Window` class itself to handle a resize event happening before `initializeBounds` is called.

The flag was made `protected` to deal with a problem in `ApplicationWindow` (see bug [289181](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=289181)) where a resize event during `Shell.setMenu` was causing problems.